# Minimum-cut with balanced and limited number of nodes in each partition: Does this have an efficient solution or even a name?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, approximation, minimum-cuts

I'd like to remove the minimum number of edges from an undirected unweighted graph to partition the nodes into an arbitrary number of connected components $S_1$, $S_2$,$S_3$,... $S_k$ while maximizing the size (number of nodes) of the smallest partition and with a constraint limiting the size of every partition: $|S_i| \leq c$ for all $i$

Example input: $c=30$; Graph with 40 nodes that are fully connected and 20 nodes that each have one edge
Example output: 30 of the fully connected nodes are placed in $S_1$ and everything else (30 nodes) is placed in $S_2$.

This is similar to minimum k-cut, but I can't find a name for this problem with arbitrary k. I can't use a minimum k-cut solver because it would break up the 10 single-edged nodes into 10 sets before it starts breaking up the 40 fully connected nodes. Closest I could find was [Most balanced minimum cuts](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X09003631), but that only deals with a single st-cut.

Approximate and probabilistic/randomized solutions are totally ok for my application if that's what it takes to get decent space/time complexity.

Backstory: I'm trying to solve a [difficult problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)) with large graphs where I can only process a small number of nodes (say 30) at a time because the problem is otherwise intractable. If these partitions have many edges to the rest of the graph, the merged solution will be sub-optimal.

Comments discussing similar problems or providing background knowledge are also appreciated!

Comment: Can any of the methods for [graph partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) be adapted for this task?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem well-defined: you've given us two different criteria (minimize the number of edges removed, maximize the size of the smallest partition) with no information about how to trade off between them.  Do you want one of those to be primary, and then break ties using the other?  Do you want some weighted combination of the two?  Something else?